# After JSON decode, all the values of one key is become zero

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode the json encoded data by following way.but it always all the values of post_count key are zero after decode. But actually the json encoded data not contain zero for that array key.

```
$news_users_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://athavannews.com/?page_id=232365&datefrom=2015-07-02+00:00:00&dateto=2015-07-02+23:59:59"), true);
```

You can check the json encoded data by pasting above url on browser and can see post_count key not all include zero. but I var_dump $news_users_data, its all post_count key contain zero. Why is that?

Comment: You sure you are not just missing the two objects that have value on the `post_count` key?

Answer (score 0):

The decoding works just fine. Please dump the result end watch it carefully. Most of the `post_count` are set to 0, because you receive this from the website. But, you can find ex.:

```
 15 => 
array (size=3)
  'id' => int 35
  'name' => string 'Risha' (length=5)
  'post_count' => string '2' (length=1)
```

If there should be more posts returned in count then the problem lays on the website, but in decoding json.

Comment: json encoded data contain non zero values for post count. but when I decode, all the values of post_count are become zero.

Comment: Can you show us the var_dump of the decoded variable?

Answer (score 0):

Not all post_count are **zero** 0. Reka, Risha, Varshini are not **zero** (0)

**Try this**

```
$news_users_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://athavannews.com/?page_id=232365&datefrom=2015-07-02+00:00:00&dateto=2015-07-02+23:59:59"), true);

print_r($news_users_data);
foreach($news_users_data as $data){
    if($data['post_count'] != 0){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

---

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 28
    [name] => Reka
    [post_count] => 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 35
    [name] => Risha
    [post_count] => 2
)
Array
(
    [id] => 20
    [name] => Varshini
    [post_count] => 2
)
```